# NSNumberFormatter - how do I truncate decimal places for high values?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumberformatter

I have set up an `NSNumberFormatter` as follows:

```
formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setGroupingSize:3];
```

However, I want to amend it so that it doesn't show decimal places for values 100,000 or greater. Is this possible without creating another formatter?

Comment: Can you please precise for international users what a "decimal place" is ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to get **3,240.45**, but **324,329** instead of **324,329.12** ?

Comment: what about `formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = NO`? I aggree with rdurand please provide the intended locale.

Comment: I answered assuming this is what jowie wants.. We'll see !

Comment: Sorry, didn't see all the replies! Yes @rdurand - that's exactly what I mean :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to truncate the decimal value of big numbers (print **324,329** instead of **324,329.12**), here is what you can do.

Create a category on `NSNumberFormatter` (New File > Objective-C Category), I called mine `TruncateHigh`. This will create two files, `NSNumberFormatter+TruncateHigh.h` and `NSNumberFormatter+TruncateHigh.m`.

**NSNumberFormatter+TruncateHigh.h :**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSNumberFormatter (TruncateHigh)

- (NSString *)customStringFromNumber:(NSNumber *)number;

@end
```

**NSNumberFormatter+TruncateHigh.m :**

```
#import "NSNumberFormatter+TruncateHigh.h"

@implementation NSNumberFormatter (TruncateHigh)

- (NSString *)customStringFromNumber:(NSNumber *)number {

    if (number.floatValue > 100000) {
        [self setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
    } else {
        [self setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
    }

    return [self stringFromNumber:number];
}

@end
```

**Usage in YourViewController.m :**

```
#import "YourViewController.h"
#import "NSNumberFormatter+TruncateHigh.h"

@implementation YourViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [formatter setGroupingSize:3];

    NSNumber *smallNumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:12386.43];
    NSNumber *bigNumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:8567386.43];

    NSLog(@"Small Number : %@", [formatter customStringFromNumber:smallNumber]);
    NSLog(@"Big Number : %@", [formatter customStringFromNumber:bigNumber]);
}

@end
```

Here is the log :

```
test[7050:11303] Small Number : 12,386.43
test[7050:11303] Big Number : 8,567,386
```

This will print numbers lesser than 100000 with 2 decimal numbers, and numbers greater with no decimal value. You can customize the code to get it to work exactly as you want it to.

Let me know if something's missing.

Comment: I think that using 2 numberformatters would be a cleaner solution. It's a bit strange that a read-only method changes the internal state of the formatter.

Comment: I agree, 2 formatters would be cleaner. But the question states "Is this possible without creating another formatter?". Answer is "yes it is, here's how !" :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! And yes, you are right, this is how to do it... However I think I'll probably stick with my two formatters. I haven't checked, but I would assume it would be the faster solution, especially as I am requesting `stringFromNumber:` on pretty much every screen update.

Comment: So are you saying then that there is no way to set up a single NSNumberFormatter (with the exception of a category or subclass) to do what I want to do?

Comment: It's possible, but you will have to change *[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];* every time you want to use it..